# Are there any entities in Minecraft Bedrock Edition that emit light?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to create an entity that emits light and so far I haven't had much luck. I've tried using the emissive block component:

```
"minecraft:block_light_emission": 0.8
```

Unfortunately for me, that didn't work out, but I expected that result. With that, I've been scouring the web and vanilla packs for a while now and I'm not having any luck with brute forcing an answer to my question.

So far I have looked at the following entities:

| Entity | Light Test Screenshot |
| --- | --- |
| Blaze | [image: Screenshot of a blaze in a blocked off 5x5x5 area.] |
| Glow Squid | [image: Screenshot of a glow squid in a blocked of 5x5x5 area.] |
| Enderman | [image: Screenshot of an enderman in a blocked off 5x5x5 area.] |
| Drowned | [image: Screenshot of a drowned in a blocked off 5x5x5 area.] |
| Magma Cube | [image: Screenshot of a magma cube in a blocked off 5x5x5 area.] |

I've also looked at the behaviors for the following non-mob entities and they didn't appear to emit light either:

- Fireball
- Small Fireball
- Dragon Fireball
- Fireworks Rocket
- Lightning Bolt
- XP Orb

So far my searching is yielding no results. Subsequently, I'm beginning to think that there are ***no*** entities that emit light, only blocks.

---

Are there any entities (not items or blocks) in Minecraft Bedrock Edition that emit light?

Comment: If you count in mobs... Blazes?

Comment: @dly yes mobs count, but it turns out blazes don't emit light either :( I wonder if the glow squid does...

Comment: The glow squid doesn't either, they only appear to glow... https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Glow_Squid#Behavior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, no entities in Minecraft Bedrock Edition emit light. (Or Java, for that matter)

The only one that you could make an argument for would be the Ender Dragon during its death animation, but this is not light in the sense you mean and rather beams of colored light that don't actually seem to increase the light level. I tested End Crystals as well as I thought I remembered them emitting light, but it turns out I was remembering the fire that they light underneath them in the end when respawning the dragon.

Some mods for Java Edition add dynamic lighting on entities such as [Dynamic Lights](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/dynamic-lights), which rapidly places and removes air and water blocks to light areas as light sources move. There is also a MCPE Bedrock add-on [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MCPE/comments/jielnf/so_i_added_dynamic_lighting_to_minecraft_bedrock/) that adds some dynamic lighting to mobs and entities. At the moment, there is no attribute/NBT data/etc that allows entities to emit light in Vanilla Bedrock or Java Edition.

Comment: Hopefully this changes in 1.18 with the deep dark's warden, but I'm pretty sure this is the correct answer as of 1.17. Thanks for the reading materials and taking the time to answer!